# Printf and Scanf with arduino language

Tags: arduino, printf, scanf

I would like to use printf and scanf within the arduino language.

I run correctly the printf in this way:
http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/Printf

But I can't use scanf. How can I use it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to take a two step approach.

First of all, since you are coding for an Arduino and the data that will be processed by a `scanf` is coming thru a Serial port, then first code a routine to read a serial port for the data that you need.  You will find that this is NOT a simple task, and that you will end up with routines to read ASCII characters of integers, letters, etc.

After you have code to read a serial port for data, then generalize it to work as a method that can be called with variable argument lists which are analyzed and the routines you coded in step one are appropriately called.

In short, there isn't a scanf equivalent for the Arduino because it has to deal with Serial I/O.

However, you might be able to short-cut the above effort by reading the Serial data into a buffer and then using a sscanf (scanf on a string of chars), but again you will need to write the wrapper that does the serial i/o and calls sscanf with the variable arguments from your own wrapper, similar to what your link is doing.

Comment: Strictly, there is no scanf because there is no stdin to provide input.  A program running on a computer typically provides a stdin in the form of the keyboard, and stdout as a console window.  Without those, you have to couple some input source to sscanf as you note.

Comment: What do you think about this? http://www.appelsiini.net/2011/simple-usart-with-avr-libc If I follow the input part does it help me?

Comment: @DarkCoffee, I followed the link, note that in about the second paragraph makes a comment about when to use the Arduino libs.  It is instructive to write you own code and when sufficiently experienced either use this lib, or write your lib to do the same!  A quick review of the link does NOT find any explicit comments about using `scanf` with redirected stdin so there might still be some problems lurking in using that lib.  Problems that you won't be able to solve until you are experienced enough to write your own version of the same lib.